# HDFS Reoccurring Error: Under-Replicated Blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Every day our Hadoop Cluster reports that there are *"Under-replicated blocks"*. It is managed through Cloudera Manager. An example of the health warning is:

> ! Under-Replicated Blocks
>
> Concerning: 767 under replicated blocks in the cluster. 3,115 total blocks in the cluster. Percentage under replicated blocks: 24.62%. Warning threshold: 10.00%.

I have been running commands that fixes the problem, but the following morning the warning is back and sometimes without any new data being added. One of the temporarily successful commands was

```
hdfs dfs -setrep -R 2 /*
```

I have also tried [another recommended command](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4427/fix-under-replicated-blocks-in-hdfs-manually.html)

```
su hdfs
hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' >> /tmp/under_replicated_files 
for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 2 $hdfsfile; done
```

Both do work, but the fix isn't permanent.

In Cloudera Manager the `Replication Factor` and `Minimal Block Replication` are both set to `2`.

Due to the problem only happening approximately once every 24h it is difficult and time consuming to attempt to fix, with trial and error being my only resort. I have no idea why this error keeps on coming back! Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Basically, if you have a data under-replicated HDFS should just automatically replicate the blocks to other data nodes to match the replication factor.
You can also run a Balancer given in CM > HDFS > Actions drop down to fix this error.
How many Data Nodes do you have in your cluster? Did you see via NN web UI which files has the under replicated blocks? Are those files are temp files created by a job. Did you see if those warning goes away without doing anything in some time once the related job is complete?

Comment: Do you have a job that runs at the same cadence as when the problem occurs?

Comment: @tk421 Unfortunately no, it seems to happen by itself without any data ingestion jobs (or any jobs, for that matter) running

Comment: @Salim Thanks for your response. I have 3 datanodes and 1 namenode in the cluster. Running the grep command for under replicated blocks I can see that almost all are files sitting in `/user/x/.Trash`! I have no idea why these are appearing overnight though. The result of an internal hadoop job perhaps?

Comment: Trash get's cleaned at daily intervals on CDH (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_mc_config_trash.html).  That's probably what's triggering this.

Comment: @tk421 Ah I see, thank you very much for pointing that out. Much appreciated! I still need to work out why the Trash files are being produced in the first place as I'm not intentionally deleting anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by setting the following HDFS configuration in Cloudera Manager:

1. Go to the HDFS service.
2. Click the Configuration tab.
3. Select Scope > NameNode.
4. `Filesystem Trash Interval`: `0 day(s)`

   Entering '0' disables the trash feature.

This property can also be configured using `fs.trash.interval`

Once I had set this I deleted all of the offending unreplicated trash blocks -
 shown by looking in the `under_replicated_files` file produced by running the following command:

```
hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' >> /tmp/under_replicated_files
```

I ended up just deleting all of .Trash for the users.

This all then stopped anything else from being moved into .Trash once it was deleted (which I realise might not be an acceptable solution for everybody but that was perfectly fine for my use case). Also the removal of all of the unreplicated blocks meant that the warning disappeared.